# Updating Failed. Invalid JSON body passed with WordPress Version: 5.5.1

Tags: wordpress

I am facing an issue when I am updating my posts.

> Updating Failed. Invalid JSON body passed.

Tried changing permalink and deactivating different plugins, but the problem is still there.

Problem Screenshot:

[image]

- WordPress Version: 5.5.1
- Theme: Newspaper V 10.3.6.1
- Website: https://thepicklesports.com/

Using Ultimate Blocks Plugin with Gutenberg, tried deactivating the plugin, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after updating WordPress. I ended up getting mine working by installing and activating "Classic Editor", and it kept working after removing the plugin. If you wrote any of your site's PHP code, It can also happen if you have code printing content to the page where it should be returning it instead.